# Storing boolean values in hidden fields for form processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have read a lot of good stuff on truthy and falsy (http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html), and in particular the differences between '==' and '===' in JavaScript. The best explanations and resources mainly from this Stack Overflow Question:

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

I am working on a form and need to store a boolean value into a hidden field with the following jQuery syntax:

`$('[name="fieldName"]').val(true);`

So I am inserting a boolean value, true or false, into the hidden field. During on screen processing, I grab this field value in a number of if-statements with the following code, and compare it as follows:

`$('[name="fieldName"]').val() === "true"`

Note how I am using the === operator to compare to the string value "true".

My question; if only Object in JavaScript is of type reference, then boolean must be a value type. I would therefore assume, as value comparisons with the === operator compare not only contents but the type, that the above expression should return false? However in my code it returns true - can anyone explain why this is?

This code previously used == for the comparison, but to avoid falsy risks I am implementing === wherever possible. Could it be something to do with jQuery converting the values for me?

Comment: What is $j in the comparing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it be something to do with jQuery converting the values for me?

HTML form elements always store the value as a string, regardless of what the actual content is.  In your case it is a `boolean`, but even if it was say a `number` type, what you would see is "10.5" not 10.5.

If you'd really like to compare boolean to boolean, what I would recommend is:

```
Boolean($j('[name="fieldName"]').val()) === true
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean() approach will not work because:

```
Boolean("true") === true;
Boolean("false") === true;
```

Seems that only way it is:

```
$j('[name="fieldName"]').val(true)
$j('[name="fieldName"]').val() === "true"
or
$j('[name="fieldName"]').val(1)
$j('[name="fieldName"]').val() === "1"
etc.
```